# Replace numbers of varying length in a string

Tags: python

I have strings like this in a file:

```
  2381         OH    209    SER     OG   1049    -0.6546         16   ; qtot 1.543
```

and I want to replace some numbers (the 1st and the 6th, "2381" & "1049") with different ones, but keeping the alignment, i.e. adding or removing blank spaces before the numbers as needed. That is, I would replace `2381` with `__24` (`_` is a blank) or `_1049` with `37628`.

I could hard-code the exact positions of each number, but those could be different with different files, and I'd like something more versatile.

Can anyone help me doing this in python? Say the code is something like:

```
# list_a and list_b contain two different mappings between integer numbers
for line in file:
  (a, b) = (int(line.split()[0]), int(line.split()[5]))
  c = list_a[a]
  d = list_b[b]
  # create "modline", as "line" where (a,b) are replaced with (c,d)
  print modline
```

In case it matters, the mappings `list_a` and `list_b` are just the order of appearance of the numbers `a`, `b`. So, if the input file has:

```
  2381         OH    209    SER     OG   1049    -0.6546         16   ; qtot 1.543
  2382         HO    209    SER     HG   1049     0.4275      1.008   ; qtot 1.971
  2379          C    209    SER      C   1048     0.5973      12.01   ; qtot 2.568
  2380          O    209    SER      O   1048    -0.5679         16   ; qtot 2
```

I want it to become:

```
     1         OH    209    SER     OG      1    -0.6546         16   ; qtot 1.543
     2         HO    209    SER     HG      1     0.4275      1.008   ; qtot 1.971
     3          C    209    SER      C      2     0.5973      12.01   ; qtot 2.568
     4          O    209    SER      O      2    -0.5679         16   ; qtot 2
```

because `2381` appears 1st, `2380` appears 4th; `1049` appears 1st (in its column), etc. So `list_a[2381] = 1` and `list_b[1049] = 1`.

But I think I know how to do that, my problem now is actually replacing the numbers in the strings, taking into account the variable number of spaces.

I should add that there's no guarantee that the numbers are unique in each line, so I can't simply rely on regex match. I have to replace the 1st and 6th numbers, not "every (or the first) instance of `2381`"

Comment: `list_a` is actually a dictionary? -- That's pretty confusing ...

Comment: @mgilson In my current working code it is a dictionary, but does it matter (in usage) if a,b,c,d are integers?

Comment: It doesn't really matter.  But (sometimes) understanding the data-structures involved are helpful to get a better picture of the problem.

Comment: Try zfill() which will fill a string to a particular length using any character you want...

Comment: @ATOzTOA -- `zfill` pads numeric strings with zero digits.  You're looking for `ljust`, or `rjust` or `center`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, I think this does it:

```
# list_a and list_b contain two different mappings between integer numbers
for line in file:
  words = re.findall("(\s*\S+)", line)
  a = int(words[0])
  b = int(words[5])
  c = list_a[a]
  d = list_b[b]
  modline = str(c).rjust(len(words[0])) + "".join(words[1:5]) + str(d).rjust(len(words[5])) + "".join(words[6:])
  print modline
```

That is, forget about the simple `split` and go regex from the beginning. What I can almost guarantee is that there will be enough spaces in the original string for the replacement string to fit there (otherwise I'd have to change the alignment in the original file, which is a different beast).

Answer (score 0):

What about something along the lines of:

```
yourstring.replace(' 2381 ','   24 ')
```

Here's how I would do it (I think):

```
def same_space_replace(s,fld,rep):
    fld = fld.rjust(len(rep))      #could use `.ljust` or `.center` as well.
    rep = rep.rjust(len(fld))
    return s.replace(fld,rep)

for line in file:
    split_line = line.split()
    a = split_line[0]
    rep_a = str(list_a[int(a)])

    b = split_line[1]
    rep_b = str(list_b[int(b)])

    modline = same_space_replace(line,a,rep_a)
    modline = same_space_replace(line,b,rep_b)
```

Comment: Sure, if I know in advance that I'd like to replace 2381 with 24. But the file has thousands of lines, and each line will require different replacements, which may have differing lengths.

Comment: Looks like regex is the way here.

Comment: @Jellby -- I'm a little confused about *how* you're figuring out the replacements.  If you could be a little more explicit about that, it might help me provide a better answer.

Comment: Note that there could be several instances of `a` and `b`, and I must replace only those in the 1st and 6th position, respectively.

Comment: @Jellby -- would `return s.replace(fld,rep,1)` help?  This will only replace the **first** occurance of `a` and `b`.

Comment: No, it wouldn't because `b` could appear earlier than the 6th place. But I think I've found a solution (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

do something like this dynamically:

```
# example with a being 2381 and b being 1049

modeline = line.replace(a, list_a[a].rjust(len(a), ' ')).replace(b, list_b[b].rjust(len(b), ' ')
```

So, this right-justifies the new number using the same amount of spaces as the old one to keep the white space, so `2381` will be converted to `__24` (with _ being a space)

Comment: Note that there could be several instances of `a` and `b`, and I must replace only those in the 1st and 6th position, respectively.